# Efficient replacement of occurrences of a list of words

Tags: python, string, performance, algorithm, data-structures

I need to censor all occurrences of a list of words with *'s. I have about 400 words in the list and it's going to get hit with a lot of traffic, so I want to make it very efficient. What's an efficient algorithm/data structure to do this in? Preferably something already in Python.

Examples:

1. "piss off" => "**** off"
2. "hello" => "hello"
3. "go to hell" => "go to ****"

Comment: Have you considered using a regex?

Comment: Your example #2 doesn't change

Comment: censoring: not that old chestnut

Comment: Censor the words on input and not when you want to show them. So you won't need to worry about traffic

Comment: @phs Regular expressions won't be efficient enough. nebffa That's on purpose to show that I specifically want to match whole words.

Comment: @JBernardo I am already censoring on input.

Comment: @marcog then what's the problem? Regex is fine for such 1-time job. And, if you don't look at word boundaries, you'll run into [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_Problem)

Comment: "Regular expressions won't be efficient enough." Really, I think `re.sub` is a good option for this and should be fairly efficient

Comment: Hi @marcog, I had not read your comment before submitting my re based solution below. Since the code is there, maybe you could try it against any other solutions you have and comment on their relative performances in the areas it matters to you? You might be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

A case-insensitive [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)-backed set implementation might fit the bill.  For each word, you'll only process a minimum of characters.  For example, you would only need to process the first letter of the word 'zoo' to know the word is not present in your list (assuming you have no 'z' expletives).

This is something that is not packaged with python, however.  You may observe better performance from a simple dictionary solution since it's implemented in C.

Comment: I'd still have to process the other letters to find the beginning of the next word. This might actually work though. I'd initially passed off on it but now I realise that matching on word boundaries makes this quite efficient.

Comment: True, but there is no way to avoid at least trivially examining every character: minimally, you must find every space (to identify boundaries).  Also keep in mind that those extra characters you process you'll only be processing to see if they are a space or not (you won't have to a relatively expensive tree lookup).

Answer (score 0):

(1) Let P be the set of phrases to censor.

(2) Precompute H = {h(w) | p in P, w is a word in p}, where h is a sensible hash function.

(3) For each word v that is input, test whether h(v) in H.

(4) If h(v) not in H, emit v.

(5) If h(v) in H, back off to any naive method that will check whether v and the words following form a phrase in P.

Step (5) is not a problem since we assume that P is (very) small compared to the quantity of input.  Step (3) is an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to time a regexp based solution against others. I have used similar regexp based substitution of one to three thousand words on a text to change phrases into links before, but I am not serving those pages to many people.

I take the set of words (it could be phrases), and form a regular expression out of them that will match their occurrence as a complete word in the text because of the '\b'.

If you have a dictionary mapping words to their sanitized version then you could use that. I just swap every odd letter with '*' for convenience here.

The sanitizer function just returns the sanitized version of any matched swear word and is used in the regular expression substitution call on the text to return a sanitized version.

```
import re
swearwords = set("Holy Cow".split())
swear = re.compile(r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(sorted(swearwords, key=lambda w: (-len(w), w))))
sanitized = {sw:''.join((ch if not i % 2 else '*' for i,ch in enumerate(sw))) for sw in swearwords}

def sanitizer(matchobj):
    return sanitized.get(matchobj.group(1), '????')

txt = 'twat prick Holy Cow ... hell hello shitter bonk'
swear.sub(sanitizer, txt)
# Out[1]: 'twat prick H*l* C*w ... hell hello shitter bonk'
```

You might want to use re.subn and the count argument to limit the number of substitutions done and just reject the whole text if it has too many profanities:

```
maxswear = 2
newtxt, scount = swear.subn(sanitizer, txt, count=maxswear)
if scount >= maxswear: newtxt = 'Ouch my ears hurt. Please tone it down' 
print(newtxt)
# 'Ouch my ears hurt. Please tone it down'
```

Answer (score 0):

like cheeken has mentioned, a `Trie` may be the thing you need, and actually, you should use [Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). Something more than a trie.

For every string, say `S` you need to process, the time complexity is approximately `O(len(S))`. I mean, Linear

And you need to build the automaton initially, it's time complexity is `O(sigma(len(words)))`, and space complexity is about(less always) `O(52*sigma(len(words)))` here **52** means the size of the alphabet(i take it as `['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z']`). And you need to do this just for once(or every time the system launches).

Answer (score -1):

If performance is what you want I would suggest:

- Get a sample of the input
- Calculate the average amount of censored words per line
- Define a max number of words to filter per line (3 for example)
- Calcule what censored words have the most hits in the sample
- Write a function that given the censored words, will generate a
  python file with IF statements to check each words, putting the 'most
  hits' words first, since you just want to match whole words it will
  be fairly simple
- Once you hit the max number per line, exit the function

**I know this is not nice** and I'm only suggesting this approach because of the high traffic scenario, doing a loop of each word in your list will have a huge negative impact on performance.

Hope that help or at least give you some out of the box idea on how to tackle the problem.